Choosing the max Q(s',a) if there are multiple Qs with the same value
I'm using a 3D Q-table to train a reinforcement learning agent where I instantiate the table with a certain values and update the values during the training process. My question is: If I need to pick the max Q(s',a) where there are multiple elements with the same max value, how should I pick the one of them?
The else statement in arg_max is where I should take the decision:
# number of layers depending on the action, and each layer of them is an array of num_states * num_states
q_table = np.zeros((num_actions, num_states, num_states))

# pick an action based on epsilon greedy policy
def get_action(self, state) -> tuple:
    if np.random.uniform(0,1) < self.epsilon:
        # take random action, action_space is Tuple(Discrete(2), Discrete(5))
        action = self.action_space.sample()
    else:
        action = self.arg_max(state)

    return action

def arg_max(self, state):
    # take action according to the max q-value in the table
    arrAct_0 = self.q_table[0, state, :]
    maxVal_0 = np.amax(arrAct_0)
    max_ind_0 = np.argwhere(arrAct_0 == maxVal_0).flatten()

    arrAct_1 = self.q_table[1, state, :]
    maxVal_1 = np.amax(arrAct_1)
    max_ind_1 = np.argwhere(arrAct_1 == maxVal_1).flatten()

    if maxVal_0 > maxVal_1:
        action = (0, random.choice(max_ind_0))
    elif maxVal_0 < maxVal_1:
        action = (1, random.choice(max_ind_1))
    else:
        # Here I should take the decision if both layers have the same max Q(s',a)

    return action

# I tried this approach but I feel that there is more effective/accurate one.
action = random.choice([(0, random.choice(max_ind_0)),
                        (1, random.choice(max_ind_1))])

